# winapi RawInput and pre XP compilers, how to link?

Tags: winapi, linker, linker-errors, raw-input

I need to use RawInput api calls from under the old compiler
which is pre xp (it is borland 5.5 specifically - and do not tell
me to use other compiler it is out of question, I need to use it)

Ist headers winuser.h and user32.lib do not contain the raw input 
calls, never header and user32.lib from other compilers do.
So it is achieveable to use such external rawinput .h definitions
and link it against newest user32.lib?

I am not so much experienced in linker stuff. Definitions compile 
but I do have unresolved externals at link

Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall GetRawInputDeviceList (tagRAWINPUTDEVICELIST *, unsigned int *, unsigned int)' referenced from C \CODE2\PROGRAM\MAIN.OBJ

Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall RegisterRawInputDevices(const tagRAWINPUTDEVICE *, unsigned int, unsigned int)' referenced from C:\CODE2\PROGRAM\MAIN.OBJ

substitution of old user32.lib with new user32.lib seem to give no effect (even
renaming it out seem to has no effect, and it seems like compiler do not touch user32.lib  at all (?)

How to make it work, much tnx for advice how to resolve this (and to not tell me
i need newer compiler, i need to do it with this old)

(fire)

// edit : fixed my mistake typo winuser.lib to user32.lib (i meant user32.lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to call APIs which do exist on some Windows platforms and not on other ones, then you must NOT bind to the associated LIB statically but dynamically (using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress). Another mechanism would be to use Delay-loaded Libraries.

Comment: ok, tnx, sound reasonably (never used it, can somebody maybe quick help me and tell what would be some references i need to use to link to raw input api this way?) :?

Comment: @mox: Would that mean that the link problem would be solved, if user32.dll was added to the delay-loaded library list in Project options?

Comment: Yes and no! Using Delay-loaded library yould also mean that you need to catch the failure (about the delay-loaded "missing" function in the library) and handle the event.

Comment: Matt Pietrek (as always when it's about PE) shows how it works (http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1298/hood/hood1298.aspx)

Comment: could you tell me a bit what i should uste to load library rawInput - should I load user32.dll and getProcAdres of getRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)) and so on (using rawinput types copied fron winuser.h ?) I use b55 on XP (rawinput was shipped with xp and is contained in user32.dll) ??

Comment: See Sample (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918705/dynamic-library-linking-at-execution) on how to Dynamic Link to a Library and Get a pointer to a function

Comment: ok, tnx, this simplicity appeals to me - i ve tested it from wikipedia example also and it seeam to link to wanted function pointer so it seem that it is done, tnx all

Answer (score 1):

`GetRawInputDeviceList` and `RegisterRawInputDevices` are both in user32.lib not in winuser.lib

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600(v=vs.85).aspx

those pages also state that you only need to include windows.h (and not winuser.h)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i meant user32.lib - headers are no problems, it compile, how to go through linker errors

Comment: it would be very strange for a windows compiler not to link against user32.lib by default. Is that Borland C++ Builder 5.5? I used Borland C++ Builder 6 in the past and I hardly remember all those project configuration tabs :)

Comment: seem he do not touch it (user32.lib) - i try to make it use not onlu his old user32.lib but newer use32.lib maybe (which contains raw input reference calls inside) (i could rename user32.lib_out and there are no complaints from it)

Comment: The definitions of those function in winuser.h are inside a `#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)` block, which means they are only defined when compiling for Windows XP and later. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx, so I asume that api doesn't even exists on pre XP environment.

Comment: my environment is win xp - only compiler is pre-xp - definitions I can put-in by hand (copy and paste) it compile ok, only linker cries

Comment: you could possibly freely download it from embarcadero pages (its about 15M but need to fill up some questions sadly), ok i will try to link up to it by load library and get proc adress (need to read up some tutorial :/)

Comment: I would first try the "Delay-load" suggestion from mox. In BCB6 I found a delay-load input field under Project > Options > Advanced linker tab. Try adding user32.dll

Comment: b55 is commandline, i was trying to link it by adding newer user32.lib at the end of commandline but it has none effect